# Strange problem with compiling c code in xcode when including glext.h

Tags: c, xcode, opengl

I have this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>    
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>    

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the line with "glext.h" it compiles and runs fine in xcode 4 if I uncomment that line I get 345 errors most of them 'expected * before *' ...
What is going on?! both gl.h and glext.h are inside the OpenGL framework but no matter if I incluhe it or not I get the same error. I tried GCC 4.2 as well as LLVM GCC 4.2 and LLVM (in this case 21 semantic and parse errors).

I am sure my lack of experience with C is causing this but I am surprised gl.h has no problem but glext.h has.

Even if I try to compile in from the command line by gcc I get lots of

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3137: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try switching gl.h and glext.h around?

Comment: You are a genius! At least new I get more meaningful errors. This exact code works on a linux box (ubuntu). Why their order causes this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug with `glext.h`.  If you look at that file, you'll see that it has a bunch of definitions that use `GLenum`, but `GLenum` isn't defined anywhere in that file.  So, before you include `glext.h`, you need to include a file that defines `GLenum`.  The easiest thing to do is to include `gl.h` first instead of second:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch these two lines around:

```
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>    
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

And it should work.